# Why do i get a segmentation fault when entering a integer using scanf?

Tags: c

I am attepting to calculate the result of a multiplication of 3 variables that have been inputted using scanf, but upon entering the Duration variable, it gives me a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
       float rate;
       rate = 0.06;
       int duration;
       float principal_amount;
       float total_interest;
   printf("Enter duration in years:");
   scanf("%d", duration);
   printf("Enter principal amount of loan:");
   scanf("%f", principal_amount);
   total_interest = principal_amount * duration * rate;
   printf("Output: %f", total_interest)
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the scanf manual and check the parameter you supply!

Comment: Did you even try researching why?  Programming is solving problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`duration` is of type `int`, but you want an integer pointer as a parameter for `scanf`,

```
scanf("%d", &duration);
```

`scanf` works by placing the appropriate bytes into a position in memory, so that as a side-effect after `scanf` completes, the value in memory at the pointer address provided will be the value that was read from the input. Since you want `duration` itself to contain this value, it means you want to read it into the memory location of `duration`, which is syntactically expressed as `&duration` ("address of `duration`").

The reason for the segmentation fault is that the integer `duration` is not initialized and therefore may contain some (undefined) value at the program start time. In terms of trying to reach a memory address by way of an integer, any integer is as good as any other, so the C runtime is happy to attempt to treat whatever value is inside `duration` as if it is a memory address, but it's a memory address that your program doesn't have permission to alter. (In many cases it will in fact be `0`, and it would be equivalent to trying to write some data into `NULL`, but this is not strictly guaranteed, and it is even theoretically possible that `duration` could randomly be initialized with an integer that does point to a valid memory location ... which could cause an even worse error by writing the result of `scanf` to that location *without* producing any visible error or segmentation fault).